# JSF Ajax call not updating dynamic list correctly in backing bean

Tags: ajax, jsf, liferay

I have the following problem. I have a list that consists of dynamically generated checkboxes. When I click once on one of those checkboxes, the value of the backing bean is ok for this call. When clicking on another checkbox, this one is fine, but the others fall back to false, even the checkmark is shown in the front-end. The same problem, when I click on a final submit button. All values in the backing bean become the state **false**.

Here is the JSF:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<f:view
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head />
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:messages/>
            <h:dataTable value="#{registration.registrationlist}" var="entry">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                    #{entry.me.name}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Status</f:facet>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{entry.checked}">
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>

            <h:commandButton value="Submit">
                <f:ajax listener="#{registration.listener}" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

This is my backing bean:

```
package de.rwd.mm.beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Registration {
    private List<RegistrationEntry> registrationlist; 

    public Registration() {
        // Populating the registrationlist from database and initialize it with false
        List<MarketingEvent> me_list;
        me_list = MarketingEventLocalServiceUtil.getAllMarketingevents();
        registrationlist = new ArrayList<RegistrationEntry>();
        for (MarketingEvent me : me_list) {
            RegistrationEntry re = new RegistrationEntry(me, false);
            registrationlist.add(re);
        }
    }

    public List<RegistrationEntry> getRegistrationlist() {
        return registrationlist;
    }

    public void setRegistrationlist(List<RegistrationEntry> registrationlist) {
        this.registrationlist = registrationlist;
    }

    public void listener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        System.out.println("listener");
        System.out.println("called by " + event.getComponent().getClass().getName());

        for (RegistrationEntry entry : registrationlist) {
            String me = entry.getMe().getName();
            boolean value = entry.isChecked();

            System.out.println(me + " " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

My RegistrationEntry class that holds the database values and the boolean for the checkbox.

```
package de.rwd.mm.beans;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import de.rwd.mm.services.model.MarketingEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RegistrationEntry {
    private MarketingEvent me;
    private boolean checked;

    public RegistrationEntry() {
    }

    public RegistrationEntry(MarketingEvent me, boolean checked) {
        this.me = me;
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public MarketingEvent getMe() {
        return me;
    }

    public void setMe(MarketingEvent me) {
        this.me = me;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }
}
```

Is @ViewScoped the right scope? Or is there anything completly wrong?

The non-ajax version works, but this is no option for me. This "portlet" is placed in several pages with much content and a page refresh looks extremly ugly. This JSF runs as portlet in Liferay 6.2.

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

PS: My Liferay 6.2.0-ce-ga1 runs in Tomcat 7.0.42

Comment: what did you debug? Looked at when and how often the constructor is called? That is the place you initialize things...

Comment: Yes, that is true! The constructor gets called every time I submit the data. So of course the list is being initialized everytime. How could I avoid this?

Comment: As a suggestion in another SO topic I added the implements Serializable to the beans. But still the constructor gets called every time. Strange.

Comment: Read about ajax, jsf and portlets/portal servers... The combination is 'important'

Comment: Did you try this code outside a portal server? Simple plain tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<f:ajax execute="@form">` setting just like this example code (it uses Lombok @Data annotation to avoid typing getter/setter methods):

The sample facet:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
  <h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
      <h:dataTable value="#{myBean.records}" var="record">
        <h:column>
          <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
          #{record.name}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
          <f:facet name="header">Selected</f:facet>
          <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{record.checked}"/>
        </h:column>
      </h:dataTable>
      <h:commandButton value="Submit">
        <f:ajax listener="#{myBean.onSubmit}" execute="@form"/>
      </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

The managed bean:

```
package x;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Named( value = "myBean" )
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable
{
  private List<MyRecord> records;

  //@EJB
  //private RecordDAO recordDAO;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init()
  {
    System.out.println( "MyBean.ini() called");
    records = new ArrayList<>();
    records.add( new MyRecord( "Name 1", false ) );
    records.add( new MyRecord( "Name 2", false ) );
    records.add( new MyRecord( "Name 3", false ) );
    records.add( new MyRecord( "Name 4", false ) );
    records.add( new MyRecord( "Name 5", false ) );
  }

  public void onSubmit( AjaxBehaviorEvent abe_ )
  {
    System.out.println( "MyBeam.onSubmit() called! Values : " + getRecordValues() );
    // You should take care about persisting data here
    //recordDAO.persistRecords( records );
  }

  protected String getRecordValues()
  {
    String s = "";
    for ( MyRecord mr : records)
      s += "( name=" + mr.getName() + ", checked= " + mr.isChecked() + " ); ";
    return s;
  }

  public MyBean()
  {
  }

}
```

The test DB record:

```
package x;

import java.io.Serializable;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class MyRecord implements Serializable
{
  private String name;
  private boolean checked;

  public MyRecord( String name_, boolean checked_ )
  {
    name = name_;
    checked = checked_;
  }
}
```

Comment: I added the execute="@form" parameter, but then my listener function doesn't get called at all.

Comment: That is why I already suspected other things to be wrong. Keep in mind that OP uses this in Liferay (portal server)

Comment: @Kukeltje I didn't see LifeRay. It is a JSF solution as the tag says. For Java EE compliant servers.

Comment: I added the liferay tag since it is mentioned in the text **AND** portals have special things to take into account when doing jsf and ajax (no personal experience, but I red a lot of Q/A on the Stackoverflow and Primefaces site to have come across this). OP should try that (in creating a [mcve])

Comment: Ok. This one works! Excuse me, my fault. I had some more input fields in my form. Especially one with a required="true". This was the reason, that the listener wasn't called the right way. I deleted the required="true" and now it works properly. Thanks alot!